# How to see background threads in Visual Studio 2010 debugger

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio, debugging

I'm trying to figure out why the application process lingers in Task Manager after the application is closed and the window disappears.

When I get VS to attach to the zombie process and break all, the threads window shows that the main thread is still alive, and a number of worker threads as well.

Some questions:

- Are worker threads necessarily background threads? If not, how do I identify the  background threads as I didn't see such a column in the window?

  Do I simply double-click on each thread in the thread window, and watch the Thread.IsBackgroundThread value?
- When I click on the main thread, the debugger doesn't show a call stack. How
  do I identify where the main thread is stuck?

Comment: Use Debug + Break All to get a stack trace.  Search for DoEvents in your code.

Answer (score -1):

I would strongly sugest you tu use WinDbg. It is not a visual debugger though it is much more powerful.
Surely I will figure you out.
To list all threads in a process use: ~. 
To switch to a certain thread ~thread_ids. 
To see stak of curent thread !clr_stack.

Brief tutorial.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/windbg_part1.aspx

Also try in google "Debuging Asp.net with windbg"

Comment: There is no indication that he is using ASP.Net

Comment: Agree. I just mean that this is how I found the most useful info on WinDbg.